# qdisc netem is adding too much delay

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, tc

I'm running the following command in order to simulate delay + jitter on a veth pair (Mininet).

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev h1-eth0 root netem delay 100ms 5ms
```

When only specifying a 100ms (without the 5ms in my example) delay, everything work as expected as a ping between the interfaces can shows that there's is indeed a 100ms delay.

```
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=100 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=100 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=19 ttl=64 time=100 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=20 ttl=64 time=100 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=21 ttl=64 time=100 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=22 ttl=64 time=100 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=23 ttl=64 time=100 ms
```

However, when adding the jitter parameter, there is indeed, most of the time, a variation from 100ms to 5ms but I'm also getting a huge delay of around 4000ms

```
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=64 ttl=64 time=104 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=65 ttl=64 time=104 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=63 ttl=64 time=4391 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=68 ttl=64 time=101 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=70 ttl=64 time=101 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=66 ttl=64 time=4393 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=71 ttl=64 time=105 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=67 ttl=64 time=4393 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=72 ttl=64 time=103 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=73 ttl=64 time=100 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=69 ttl=64 time=4390 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=78 ttl=64 time=102 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=74 ttl=64 time=4392 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=75 ttl=64 time=4393 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=80 ttl=64 time=102 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=76 ttl=64 time=4393 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=77 ttl=64 time=4390 ms
```

EDIT : I just checked if this issue also occurs on a real interface, it does.

Am I missing something or is there indeed an issue?

Comment: Can't reproduce this using a simple namespace with `ip netns` on kernel 5.13.x. Moreover, in my test the jitter makes delay be 100±5 ms (so from ~ 95ms to ~ 105ms) while in your example it never drops *below* 100ms. Can you reproduce your problem *without* mininet? steps for environment without mininet: `ip netns add xp; ip l add h1-eth0 up type veth peer netns xp name eth0; ip -n xp l set eth0 up; ip a add 10.0.0.1/30 dev h1-eth0; ip -n xp a add 10.0.0.2/30 dev eth0; tc qdisc add dev h1-eth0 root netem delay 100ms 5ms; ping 10.0.0.2`

Comment: Yeah I tested it without it and I'm still experiencing the same issue. However adding `distribution normal` seems to remove the extra delay.